# Extract one column as rows with R, preserving other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, reshape2, tidyr

**What I have:**

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
sequence foo model output real
       1   3     a     12   12
       1   3     b     29   12
       1   3     c     10   12
       1   3     d     38   12
       1   3     e     10   12
       2   3     a     38   15
       2   3     b     10   15
       2   3     c     29   15
       2   3     d     56   15
       2   3     e     10   15
```

Created by:

```
d.test = data.frame(
  sequence = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  foo = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  model = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  output = c(12, 29, 10, 38, 10, 38, 10, 29, 56, 10),
  real = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15)
)
```

The model predicts an `output` for every given `sequence`, but the `real` output is also recorded along every sequence.

**What I need:**

I would like to transform the data such that `real` becomes a "model" itself, that is:

```
sequence foo model output
       1   3     a     12
       1   3     b     29
       1   3     c     10
       1   3     d     38
       1   3     e     10
       1   3  real     12
       2   3     a     38
       2   3     b     10
       2   3     c     29
       2   3     d     56
       2   3     e     10
       2   3  real     15
```

How can I achieve that using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and their cousins?

Note that for a “nice” solution, one should not have to:

- Manually enter column indices
- Manually specify all the columns like `foo` which are not of interest

**What I've tried:**

I tried the following, but it feels clumsy:

```
unique(
  melt(d.test,
    id.vars = c("sequence", "foo"),
    measure.vars = c("real"),
    variable.name = "model",
    value.name = "output"
  )
)
```

Now I have to remove the `real` column from the original data frame and append the rows of what I just did. It's not a nice solution because apart from the `foo` column there may be many more columns that I'd like to preserve, and then I'd have to specify them as `id.vars`.

Comment: Fwiw, I think reshape2 and it's melt are now ancestors, not cousins, to dplyr et al.

Comment: I know, I'm just having a hard time forcing myself to use the “new” ones :)

Comment: Don't think you are interested in a `data.table` solution, but something like `DT[,list(model=c(model,"real"),output=c(output,real[1])),by=sequence]` should work for your case. (`DT` is of course `as.data.table(d.test)`).

Comment: @nicola Interesting, thank you. Never really used `data.table`, but it's good to have that as a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d.test)

d.test[, 
  rbind(.SD, .SD[1L][, `:=`(model = "real", output = real[1L])])
, by=sequence][, real := NULL][]
```

---

If I had to use the 'verse:

```
d.real = d.test %>% distinct(sequence) %>%
  mutate(model = "real", output = real) %>% select(-real)

d = d.test %>% select(-real)
```

And then stack them:

```
bind_rows(d, d.real)
```

If the ordering is important, add `%>% arrange(sequence)`.

---

*Comment.* The problem in the OP originates with untidy data. Reading [Hadley's paper on the subject](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10) would probably be helpful if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: Oh, d'oh, just realized this is what the OP had already thought of. Nonetheless, it seems like the right way to go.

Comment: That looks nicer than the `reshape2/unique` solution, but I would like not to have to specify all other columns like `foo` manually, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to widen the already-long data and then convert it back into long form, making sure to include the `real` column in the reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d.test %>%
  spread(model, output) %>%
  gather(model, output, -sequence, -foo) %>%
  arrange(sequence, model)
#>    sequence foo model output
#> 1         1   3     a     12
#> 2         1   3     b     29
#> 3         1   3     c     10
#> 4         1   3     d     38
#> 5         1   3     e     10
#> 6         1   3  real     12
#> 7         2   3     a     38
#> 8         2   3     b     10
#> 9         2   3     c     29
#> 10        2   3     d     56
#> 11        2   3     e     10
#> 12        2   3  real     15
```

`spread` is the tidyr function for widening long data. It takes a data-frame, the name of a column of keys (variable names), and the name of a column of values, and spreads the keys out over several columns. This is how the data looked after spreading the `model`-`output` pairs into several columns.

```
# Convert to wide-format so there is one real per row
d.test.wide <- d.test %>%
  spread(model, output)
d.test.wide
#>   sequence foo real  a  b  c  d  e
#> 1        1   3   12 12 29 10 38 10
#> 2        2   3   15 38 10 29 56 10
```

`gather` is the tidyr function for melting data. We use dplyr's column-selection syntax, and we tell it gather all of the columns except the identifiers `sequence` and `foo`, storing the keys in a `model` column and the values in `output` column.

We could also explicitly select the columns to gather: `d.test.wide %>% gather(model, output, real, a:e)`. The leftover unselected columns will be used as identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to proceed would be:

```
temp = unique(d.test[,-c(3,4)])
temp$model = "real"
colnames(temp)[3] = "output"
d.test$real = NULL
d.test = rbind(d.test,temp)
```

This returns:

```
> d.test
   sequence foo model output
1         1   3     a     12
2         1   3     b     29
3         1   3     c     10
4         1   3     d     38
5         1   3     e     10
6         2   3     a     38
7         2   3     b     10
8         2   3     c     29
9         2   3     d     56
10        2   3     e     10
11        1   3  real     12
61        2   3  real     15
```

**Edit:**
If you want to avoid harcoding the column index of model and output, do:

```
temp = unique(d.test[,!grepl("(model|output)",colnames(d.test))])
```

and

```
colnames(temp)[which(colnames(temp)=="real")] = "output"
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work, but it's very dependent on manually entered column indices, whereas a clean solution would simply specify the column names you're interested in. I've clarified that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
 x <- unique(
         melt(d.test,
              id.vars = c("sequence", "foo"),
              measure.vars = c("real"),
              variable.name = "model",
              value.name = "output" ))

d.test$real<-NULL

names(x) <- names(d.test)

rbind(d.test, x)
```

Comment: The output is what I want, yes, but  in the question I already described that I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with dplyr:

```
 > library(dplyr)
    > 
    > 
    > d.real <- d.test %>% group_by(sequence) %>%
                 select(foo=unique(foo),output = unique(real))  %>% 
                 unique() %>% mutate(model='real') %>% as.data.frame() %>% rbind(d.test[,1:4]) 
                 %>% arrange(sequence,model)
    Adding missing grouping variables: `sequence` #ignore it
    > 
    > knitr::kable(d.real)


    | sequence| foo| output|model |
    |--------:|---:|------:|:-----|
    |        1|   3|     12|a     |
    |        1|   3|     29|b     |
    |        1|   3|     10|c     |
    |        1|   3|     38|d     |
    |        1|   3|     10|e     |
    |        1|   3|     12|real  |
    |        2|   3|     38|a     |
    |        2|   3|     10|b     |
    |        2|   3|     29|c     |
    |        2|   3|     56|d     |
    |        2|   3|     10|e     |
    |        2|   3|     15|real  |
```